# Master Page display goes with Authorization

Tags: asp.net

I am using the `authorization` section in web.config:

```
<authorization>
   <allow roles="Administrator,Attorney,Director of Operations,Office Manager,Paralegal,Partner,Processor,Salary Admin,Unit Manager"/>
   <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

With this code in place, my master page CSS, as well as my images go away, and when I remove this from the web.config it displays properly.  Any idea why it is showing that way?  Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This `authorization` section also applies to your CSS files and images.  You need to use the `location` element to give anonymous access back to these files.  [Here's a knowledge base article about this.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871)  Your web.config should look something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <!-- This is your section from your question -->
    <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrator,Attorney,Director of Operations,Office Manager,Paralegal,Partner,Processor,Salary Admin,Unit Manager"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <!-- Now give everyone access to your "images" folders -->
  <location path="Images">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Check this as well:http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx

Comment: hi, iam writing   <location path="Salary.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Salary Admin" />
        <deny users="*"/> 
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location> in web. config this is working perfectly fine.. but i want to display appropraie message to user that he is not authorized and give a link to go back but instead it going in login form direclty.. any help wil be appreciated.

Comment: i got something like this form Stackoverflow itself.. protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {     if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)     {         base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);     }     else     {         filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "AccessDenied" };     } }  but its not too working either